# What does "ignoring (possibly broken) abi-depends field for packages" mean?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I've got this warning

```
ignoring (possibly broken) abi-depends field for packages
```

when run `cabal build` with my small project. What does it mean? And when I use usual `ghc -O2 mylib.lhs` I've got no such warning, why?

Haskell Platform with ghc 8.4.3 on Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this issue https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5465 message appears "whenever a package registration (IPI) includes a abi-depends: field", thought to be redundant and removed in future releases.

Comment: So, as far as I understand your answer -- It isn't problem at all?